# Incorrect extracted text from image and how to improve tesseract-ocr 3.0 for C#?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I am having trouble extracting text from image using tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe in .NET
     I have used simple yatt class  (yatt / tesseract-ocr-class.cs) from [**here**](https://gist.github.com/yatt/915443)

I have Downloaded and installed  esseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe from [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=)
Then use the yatt class in C# like this

```
        TesseractOCR ocr = new TesseractOCR(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe");          
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\ocr\cap.jpg"))
        divOCRText.InnerHtml = ocr.OCRFromBitmap(bmp);
```

Its extracting text from image but there are many-2 issues. Extracted text has many spelling mistakes. Can somebody guide me what am I doing wrong?

**Here is the Image to OCR**

[image]

**Extracted Text (Screenshot)**

[image]

**Here is the testdata install in my PC**

[image]

Comment: Writing bold text doesn't make your question better. Please reformat it..

Comment: apologies..Reformatted.